# Setup Gedit For C++ Development

Tags: c++, linux, svn, gedit

I'm starting in C++ development, but i like to use Gedit for writing the files, but like for Ruby on Rails and many other languages, are some tools and configurations for Gedit that makes develop more easy and comfortable, and another question, what is the best for C++, SVN, CVS, Git and others...? Thanks, and sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For editing you can choose:

- just an editor - vi(m), emacs, etc. Here I prefer vim. But if you're not 
  familiar with it you may be shocked at the begging. These give posibility also run make from within the editor itself.
- IDE - KDevelop, Eclipse (+ CDT - plugin for C++), Code::Blocks. I didn't used by these, 
  but heard from colleagues that KDevelop is ok, while Eclipse is too have ans slow.

As for source control the choice is between SVN (this is right successor of CVS) and git.
If you develop alone or it's not big team of developers SVN should be fine. It uses central repository to store the data.

git in contrast is distributed source control tool. I found it pretty complicated to used to.

So if you don't need "distributed" feature of git, choose SVN.

Comment: Thanks idimba, i'm reading about SVN, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 8):

The two most important plugins for Gedit are "External Tools" (allows you to run make or whatever other command you want with a keystroke) and "Snippets" (avoids retyping boilerplate code).
Also, have a look at http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins, you will probably find something useful.

As for version control - I would recommend git, it is faster and has more features. SVN can work OK too. Do not use CVS unless someone points a gun at your head.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, gedit has plugins nowadays?
I was about to suggest emacs/gvim or a full blown IDE like anjuta for coding cpp.

Regarding the choice of version control, I'd go with svn or git. Both are very easy to use and don't make you jump through hoops like the good old cvs.

Comment: I dislike emacs/gvim, because they are so much confused and an IDE for me that is starting is not a good idea. Thanks!